# PL/SQL regex match commas not inside quotes

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, split

I have a comma-separated string and I need to match all the commas in this string except for the commas inside the double-quotes. I'm using regex for this.

```
,,,,"8000000,B767-200","B767-200","Boeing 767-200","ACFT",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I tried the following regex patterns but none of them are working in PL/SQL but working in online regex testers.

```
,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))

(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)
```

I'm using REGEXP_INSTR function inside a procedure in PL/SQL to identify the index of the commas. Can someone suggest me a working regex pattern in PL/SQL for this purpose or help me to write one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not support look-ahead and non-capturing groups so you will need to match the quotes.

Assuming you can either have a non-quoted string or a quoted string (which could contain escaped quotes) then you can the regular expression:

```
([^",]*|"(\\"|[^"])*"),
```

Which you could use like this:

```sql
WITH matches ( id, csv, start_pos, comma_pos, idx,  num_matches ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         csv,
         1,
         REGEXP_INSTR( csv, '([^",]*|"(\\"|[^"])*"),', 1, 1, 1, NULL ) - 1,
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT( csv, '([^",]*|"(\\"|[^"])*"),' )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         csv,
         REGEXP_INSTR( csv, '([^",]*|"(\\"|[^"])*"),', 1, idx + 1, 0, NULL ),
         REGEXP_INSTR( csv, '([^",]*|"(\\"|[^"])*"),', 1, idx + 1, 1, NULL ) - 1,
         idx + 1,
         num_matches
  FROM   matches
  WHERE  idx < num_matches
)
SELECT id,
       idx,
       start_pos,
       comma_pos,
       SUBSTR( csv, start_pos, comma_pos - start_pos ) AS value
FROM   matches
```

so for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, csv ) AS
SELECT 1, ',,,,"8000000,B767-200","B767-200","Boeing 767-200","ACFT",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,' FROM DUAL
```

which outputs:

> ```
> ID | IDX | START_POS | COMMA_POS | VALUE             
> -: | --: | --------: | --------: | :-----------------
>  1 |   1 |         1 |         1 | null              
>  1 |   2 |         2 |         2 | null              
>  1 |   3 |         3 |         3 | null              
>  1 |   4 |         4 |         4 | null              
>  1 |   5 |         5 |        23 | "8000000,B767-200"
>  1 |   6 |        24 |        34 | "B767-200"        
>  1 |   7 |        35 |        51 | "Boeing 767-200"  
>  1 |   8 |        52 |        58 | "ACFT"            
>  1 |   9 |        59 |        59 | null              
>  1 |  10 |        60 |        60 | null              
>  1 |  11 |        61 |        61 | null              
>  1 |  12 |        62 |        62 | null              
>  1 |  13 |        63 |        63 | null              
>  1 |  14 |        64 |        64 | null              
>  1 |  15 |        65 |        65 | null              
>  1 |  16 |        66 |        66 | null              
>  1 |  17 |        67 |        67 | null              
>  1 |  18 |        68 |        68 | null              
>  1 |  19 |        69 |        69 | null              
>  1 |  20 |        70 |        70 | null              
>  1 |  21 |        71 |        71 | null              
>  1 |  22 |        72 |        72 | null              
>  1 |  23 |        73 |        73 | null              
>  1 |  24 |        74 |        74 | null              
>  1 |  25 |        75 |        75 | null              
>  1 |  26 |        76 |        76 | null              
>  1 |  27 |        77 |        77 | null              
>  1 |  28 |        78 |        78 | null              
>  1 |  29 |        79 |        79 | null              
>  1 |  30 |        80 |        80 | null              
>  1 |  31 |        81 |        81 | null              
>  1 |  32 |        82 |        82 | null              
>  1 |  33 |        83 |        83 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f9f54adb79b1ac5c66f9b11d048eee71)*

*(Note: you wanted to match the commas and this regular expression does exactly what you ask; it does not match any final value in the comma-delimited list as there is no terminating comma. If you wanted to do that then use the regular expression `([^",]*|"(\\"|[^"])*")(,|$)` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8d4422a60df13afb63dd6cfe029ebad2).)*

If you want it in a procedure then:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE extract_csv_value(
  i_csv   IN VARCHAR2,
  i_index IN INTEGER,
  o_value OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
  o_value := REGEXP_SUBSTR( i_csv, '([^",]*|"(\\"|[^"])*")(,|$)', 1, i_index, NULL, 1 );

  IF SUBSTR( o_value, 1, 1 ) = '"' THEN
    o_value := REPLACE( SUBSTR( o_value, 2, LENGTH( o_value ) - 2 ), '\"', '"' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

then:

```sql
DECLARE
  csv   VARCHAR2(4000) := ',,,,"8000000,B767-200","B767-200","Boeing 767-200","ACFT",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,';
  value VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
    extract_csv_value( csv, i, value );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( LPAD( i, 2, ' ' ) || ' ' || value );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

outputs:

> ```
>  1 
>  2 
>  3 
>  4 
>  5 8000000,B767-200
>  6 B767-200
>  7 Boeing 767-200
>  8 ACFT
>  9 
> 10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3d58f1a2933c2cd7591270dd09b40ffa)*

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve it without using a `REGEX` so check the following PROCEDURE if  works as expected.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_extract(p_string IN VARCHAR) AS
    TYPE table_result IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    t_retval table_result;

    opening BOOLEAN := FALSE;
    cnt INTEGER := 1;
    I INTEGER := 1;
    j INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN

    WHILE cnt <= LENGTH(p_string) AND cnt <> 0 LOOP
        IF substr(p_string, cnt, 1) = '"'THEN
            opening := NOT opening;
        END IF;

        IF opening THEN
            I := instr(p_string, '"', cnt + 1, 1);
            t_retval(t_retval.COUNT + 1) := substr(p_string, cnt, I - cnt + 1);
        END IF;

        cnt := instr(p_string, '"', cnt + 1, 1);
    END LOOP;

    FOR K IN t_retval.FIRST..t_retval.LAST LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(t_retval(K));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Test it.

```
BEGIN
    p_extract(',,,,"8000000,B767-200","B767-200","Boeing 767-200","ACFT",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,');
END;

--OUTPUT
/*
"8000000,B767-200"
"B767-200"
"Boeing 767-200"
"ACFT"
*/
```

**However this won't work if you miss the last or first "**